# Nodejs Commander required argument removes quotation marks of my data

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I'm building basic http cli client with sockets instead of using axios or fetch. In my CLI post request I'm entering my inline json data like `http post -d '{"coassign":1 }' url`

but when I fetch the value by using `option.inline` it gives me `{coassign:1}` (without quotation marks). so, when I try to post data as json it shows empty

```
PS C:\Users\Imjimil> httpc post -h Content-Type:application/json -d '{"Assignment": 1}' 'http://www.httpbin.org/post'
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{Assignment: 1}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
  "Content-Length": "15",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Host": "www.httpbin.org",
  "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-633dbbde-332b92624994b3fa711c94a1"
},
"json": null,
"origin": "96.20.207.134",
"url": "http://www.httpbin.org/post"
}
```

here json is empty, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: We need to see some code to know what is happening. How was the option read from the command line, and how was the `json` property setup?

Comment: From discussion on your duplicate question, it sounds like you are having problems with quoting in the shell you are using. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248616/discussion-on-question-by-jimil-json-parse-not-working-on-my-string-variable

Answer (score 0):

It is not Commander removing the quotes. Are you perhaps parsing that option value as json in your code?

Also in case it is the shell processing stripping the quotes, check what argument you are actually receiving in the code.

```js
const { Command } = require('commander');

console.log(process.argv.slice(2));

const program = new Command();
program.option('-d, inline <value>');
program.parse();

console.log(`Parse option is: ${program.opts().inline}`);
```

```
$ node index.js -d '{"Assignment": 1}'
[ '-d', '{"Assignment": 1}' ]
Parse option is: {"Assignment": 1}
```